# Resuming Activity Android

Tags: android, android-activity, resume

I have 4 activities,
A B C D
A is Menu and it's contained from 3 buttons that start other 3 activities, B C D.
What I want, I want when I start B C D activity and decide to go to menu, to show Menu. It's working but there is a problem. Always when I go back to Menu, there is a Copy of Menu Activity.
So how can I set it to resume activity not create new one?
But Without destroying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any code, its a little unclear what your problem is but I think what you want is to set an `Intent.Flag`. When starting the `Activity` add this flag to your `Intent`

```
Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivityName.this, MenuActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);  // set the flag
startActivity(i);[
```

and don't call `finish()` in your menu `Activity`.

[Intent Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)